# How to install google consent script for CMP banner?

Tags: laravel

```
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag() {
 dataLayer.push(arguments);
}
gtag("consent", "default", {
ad_storage: "Denied",
analytics_storage: "Denied",
wait_for_update: 1000
});
 gtag('set', 'url_passthrough', true);
```

google consent mode isnt working i'm beginner here thanks in advance for help

Comment: did  you use this script
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=GA_MEASUREMENT_ID"></script>

Comment: Yes, I already added this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this one

```
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        function gtag() {
            dataLayer.push(arguments);
        }
        gtag("consent", "default", {
            ad_storage: "denied",
            analytics_storage: "denied",
            wait_for_update: 1000
        });
          gtag('set', 'url_passthrough', true);
          gtag("set", "ads_data_redaction", true);
```

src [content](https://support.seersco.com/en/how-to-activate-google-consent-mode)